# Why am I getting a "DeprecationWarning: 'originalKeywordKind' deprecated" error when attempting to compile my project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

After compiling my project, I get the error pasted below, what does this mean and how can I fix it?

```
- info Linting and checking validity of types
DeprecationWarning: 'originalKeywordKind' has been deprecated since v5.0.0 and will no longer be usable after v5.2.0. Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead.
```

[image: while npm run build]

I'm using nextjs 13.4 and my dependencies are as follows:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.12",
    "next": "^13.4.12",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-uuid": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.4.1",
    "prisma": "^5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This refers to a change in Typescript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/deprecatedCompat/5.0/identifierProperties.ts#L28

And something, probably one of your dependencies, haven't adapted to that change just yet, but it's only a deprecation warning, so no worries at the moment.

Comment: The moment is over. :) Any idea how to fix it? I want to send a PR to ts-utils but I can't find any documentation on the change other than that error message.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out: 

https://github.com/ajafff/tsutils/pull/156/files

Answer (score 12):

Just update `@typescript-eslint/parser` to latest (^6.6.0), it's an indirect dependency that was importing `tsutils`.

Also, these dependencies should be in `devDependencies` section:

```
"@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
"@types/node": "^20.4.5",
"@types/react": "^18.2.16",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
"eslint": "^8.45.0",
"eslint-config-next": "^13.4.12",
"typescript": "^5.1.6"
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this when I upgraded a NestJS application's underlying typescript installation to take advantage of new TS features like `satisfies`.

Aside from Munchy's answer of why, the fix this problem is updating all packages having to do with linting using `npm i -D <package-name>@latest`, such as:

```
eslint
eslint-config-prettier
eslint-plugin-prettier
prettier
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser
```

Updating these got rid of the warnings, and it's good practice to keep dev dependencies up-to-date.

Comment: In my case, it came from tsutils, which is a dependency of eslint-plugin-etc. Until tsutils is updated with TypeScript 5 support, my options are to hold off on upgrading TypeScript to 5.2 or turn off eslint-plugin-etc rules.

Comment: For me the cause was tslint, importing tsutils. Found out by scanning my package-lock.json