# How do I find a package with a deprecated dependency?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Referring to this question specifically: [DeprecationWarning: 'originalKeywordKind' deprecated Use 'identifierToKeywordKind(identifier)' instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76769634/deprecationwarning-originalkeywordkind-deprecated-use-identifiertokeywordkin)

I have this exact issue.

How do I locate all packages and their dependencies which depend on this deprecated feature?